# \bm command affects other macros

Tags: bold, sans-serif, boldmath, bm

I want to use bold sf-fonts to designate a special kind of variable. I do this by using the `bm` package and then wrapping `\mathsf` in `\bm`.

Unfortunately, this approach has the side effect that somehow other text is also printed in bold but only in certain cases. The whole thing is rather weird.

```latex
\documentclass{acmart}
\usepackage{bm}

\newcommand{\mybold}[1]{\ensuremath{\bm{\mathsf{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\func}[1]{\mathit{func}\left(#1\right)}
\newcommand{\xy}{\mybold{xy}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \func{a~\xy}
    \func{a} 
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
    \func{a} 
    \func{a~\xy}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
    \func{a~\xy}\\
    \func{a} 
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
    \func{a} \\
    \func{a~\xy}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Produces this output:

[image: output of the latex code]

The first line happens to look like what I want, but since it seems dependent on the order of expressions, the whole macro more often than not produces the wrong outputs.

Is there any way to restrict this style to `xy`?

Comment: I don't know what the explanation is but I am sure someone will help. Meantime I only get the _unexpected_ output if I compile your code by `pdflatex`. Any other engine, such as `xelatex`, and `lualatex` produce the correct output.

Comment: I can't test now but it sounds like this bug https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/1028

Comment: I checked . It is the bug and the next latex will repair that. You can use `\setcounter{localmathalphabets}{0}` for a work-around now.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I was just going to say the same....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle so slow ...

Comment: @Celdor with pdftex you need 15 fonts to see the issue with xetex you need 255

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks but I still need to learn about fonts and font related issues.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer this indeed solved the problem! If you write your comment in an answer I can mark it correct!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a bug which will be resolved with the next LaTeX release https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/1028

As a work-around you can for now add `\setcounter{localmathalphabets}{0}`:

```
\documentclass{acmart}
\usepackage{bm}

\newcommand{\mybold}[1]{\ensuremath{\bm{\mathsf{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\func}[1]{\mathit{func}\left(#1\right)}
\newcommand{\xy}{\mybold{xy}}
\setcounter{localmathalphabets}{0}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \func{a~\xy}
    \func{a} 
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
    \func{a} 
    \func{a~\xy}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
    \func{a~\xy}\\
    \func{a} 
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
    \func{a} \\
    \func{a~\xy}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you need `bm` for this purpose.

```
\documentclass{acmart}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbfsf}{\encodingdefault}{\sfdefault}{b}{n}
\newcommand{\mybold}[1]{\mathsf{#1}}
\newcommand{\func}[1]{\mathit{func}(#1)}
\newcommand{\xy}{\mathbfsf{xy}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \func{a\,\xy}
    \func{a}
\\
    \func{a}
    \func{a\,\xy}
\\
    \func{a\,\xy}\\
    \func{a}
\\
    \func{a} \\
    \func{a\,\xy}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without loading `bm`, the count of math groups falls down to 12.